# Keeping chapter on same page in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

In my table of content, I have 6 chapters (plus appendices). The second chapter begins at the first page of the toc, and ends at the second. I'd like to know if there is a way to move it up to the first page without bringing the titles closer to each other. Note that the second chapter is not the last one. Below is a picture of the situation. Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{3\baselineskip}}` before your `\chapter{Preliminaries}`. Untested. You could try the unstarred version of `\enlargethispage` and/or change the number of `\baselineskip`s.

Comment: This actually works, but then the numbering of the page (i) becomes very close to the last subsection of chapter 2.

Comment: Changing the location of the page number on this page would require major surgery, and probably affect the rest of the document, so not a good idea.  Maybe, in this one case, it would it be appropriate to use `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my comment into an answer with an addition. Try:

```
...
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{3\baselineskip}}
\chapter{Preliminaries} % your second chapter
...
```

which will increase the textheight on the particular page in the ToC where chapter **Preliminaries** occurs. You could also try the unstarred version of `\enlargethispage` and change the enlargement amount.

As you said in your comment the above leaves little space between the last ToC entry and the page number for your document. You could reduce the amount of space between the ToC title and the first entry along the lines:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%...
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-4em}}
\chapter{One}
%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\enlargethispage*{3\baselineskip}}
\chapter{Preliminaries}
%
\end{document}
```

You need to choose the lengths to best suit your document.

But perhaps you are trying to squeeze too much on the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a more automatic solution, try

```
% prevent page breaks before a subsection
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\penalty10000}%
    \oldsubsection%
}
% prevent page breaks before a section
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\penalty10000}%
    \oldsection%
}
```

You can optimise the penalty value (10000=never break, 1=make it slightly less likely to break here). Note that this can stretch your table of contents quite a bit. If you want the extra vertical space on the bottom of the page, try:

```
{\raggedbottom\tableofcontents}
```

If you want the extra vertical space in between the chapters, try:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vfil}%
    \oldchapter%
}

[...]

\tableofcontents
\vfill
```